# How to give ActiveAdmin its own application layout? -- Rails newbie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

It's probably a dead simple question. Right now it uses the default application layout file. How can I create one just for AdminAdmin in order keep it separate from the one used on the main site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [layouts and rendering guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render), there is paragraph about `:layout` option.

You can specify layout, or set it to false, to render without layout at all.

```
render :layout => 'special_layout'
render :layout => false
```

Answer (score 0):

If my memory does not fail me again !! ;-)

this [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin?autoplay=true) talk about this.  But i'm not sure!

Anyway, if you never watched it.  It's a good watch.