# Overriding "application.html.erb" for ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

> **Disclaimer**: I'm quite a novice to RoR, but not with Ruby (if that 
>   makes sense). I come from a Zend background and even, I was more used to 
>   hacking Wordpress installations and then Drupal based ones. I'm well 
>   acquainted with MVC models so here goes nothing.

I'd like to use my site's layout instead of the prepackaged layout that I've implemented in my Rails app instead of using `ActiveAdmin`. I've [seen a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084183/how-to-give-activeadmin-its-own-application-layout-rails-newbie) to something close but it's not cutting it. I'm hoping to use my site's `application.html.erb` to provide an uniform experience all around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem with the link you provided? It sounds like what you're after.

```
render layout: '/layouts/application'
```

In what way does this not work for you?

Comment: 1. I'm not sure where to put this line, I'm quite new to how Rails works and what not.

Comment: Put it in as the last line of the controller method you're working with.

Comment: It doesn't work like that; I'd have to edit the gem, I'm trying to do that without editing the gem. Or at least duck facing it.